# how to read specific line read from file

Tags: c

I have managed to read all the lines in my file to a char array but when I want to read a specific line i.e. line 254 as in the example below, I always get the data in the last line in my file. Any idea what's the problem. Thank you.
Here is sample of the code:

```
 while (fgets(line,2000,fp)!=NULL
{
 readData [n] = line;
 n++;
}
printf ("print line after %s\n",readData [254]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're copying the pointer every time. So at the end every entry of the `readData` array will point to the same memory. Try to copy the data instead:

```
readData[n] = strdup(line);
```

And remember to `free` when done. If you don't have `strdup` or don't want to use it:

```
readData[n] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
strcpy(readData[n], line);
```

Comment: Hi Cnicutar, where do I use the free(readData[n]) please. is it just before I close the file? or whithin the loop.thanks

Comment: @user999 You call `free` when you decide "I no longer have any use for `readData[n]`.

Comment: that great, thanks again. I have another question if that's ok. What I read from readData[254] line has 4 argument as this: 1.56 2.47 5.69 3.48. I need to access each of these arguments seperately i.e. array[0] should return 1.56 as a float no. Highly appreciate your advise.

Comment: @user999 You can use `sscanf`.

Comment: Hi again, I have just done that but everytime it returns 0 not 1.56.  I have used: sscanf(readData[254],"%f", &State[254]). printf("\n state 1: %2.3f", &State[254]); Thank you

Comment: sorry I meant printf("\n state 1: %2.3f", &State[0]);

Comment: @cnicutar is there a way to do this without having to call `strcpy` from within a `while` loop?  Like: `char buf[BUFSIZ]; while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)!= NULL) { skipLine(); n++; } strcpy(buffer[n], buf);`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing "readData" is an array of char*s, so when you say `readData[n] = line` you are always setting the array to the same "buffer" of data.

You need something a bit more like

```
char buffer[numLines][colsPerLine];
char line[colsPerLine];
while (fgets(line,2000,fp)!=NULL
{
   strcpy(buffer[n], line); // copy contents of line into the buffer
   n++;
}
printf ("print line after %s\n",buffer[254]);
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much cnicutar and John3136 for your neat suggestion.

Comment: what are some sane/optimal defaults/values to use in the definition of `char buffer` and `char line`?  Where's `numLines` and `colsPerLine` coming from?

Answer (score -1):

You can use seek pointer to move cursor to line no . And then apply reading line .
Hope it will work.